# Analysing papers and providing search

Tags: publishing

Suppose I want to provide "smart" (AI, meaning extraction etc.) search over many published papers (specifically, biological) to simplify researchers' live.

Now, I have access to my university library that contains text of many papers from different sources, including those with payed subscription.

Is it legal to download all papers, analyse them and provide search without disclosing full text of the paper, only small part of text or image and with proper citation?

Comment: You need a legal opinion, not one from a biologist. Your question is therefore off-topic and I have voted to close it. However, apart from the obvious step of looking at the conditions associated with download of papers from (?) — probably through — your library, you should consult your University librarian. I seem to have read that many journals do not allow such data mining. You are certainly not the first to think of doing this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a legal question, not one about biology.

Comment: Can we talk about this? contact me at http://Keybase.io/gabefair

Comment: Could [Academia stackexchange](https://academia.stackexchange.com/) would be a better fit for migration?

Comment: I don't have enough reputation on biology exchange so I'm unable to close the question myself. If somebody can close it, please do, I'll ask it on Academia stackexchange as @AlwaysConfused suggested

Comment: @AlwaysConfused https://law.stackexchange.com/ would be better.